# User is trying to save a dashboard but the only option she has is private, can you make it so she can save to all folders?

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, user-admin, reports-folder, einstein-analytics-dashboards

User is trying to save a dashboard but the only option she has is private, can you make it so she can save to all folders?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Permission Set, add the Manage Public Dashboards permission, and assign it to this user. They can then create new folders and dashboards, edit existing ones, and remove them. To allow access to just certain folders, you can click the menu icon for the folder, Share, then grant Manager access to the folder.

Comment: In my org there is already a permission set named manage public dashboard.so i have added the user into it..will it work?

Comment: @Harishk Presumably.

Comment: Can i get your mail id please??